# Problem in get the data on my web site with node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm not getting any data from my ServerSide.js file in my directory when I submit a name and a text on my form. It all belongs to my root folder, so I just created this server side in a subfolder JS. I run the server on cmd and submit in my web. but on my http://127.0.0.1:3000/
just appear ' Cannot GET / ' and

```
127.0.0.1/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();

//Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was
//deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {

  var lName = req.body.Nome;
  var messg = req.body.Questio;


  res.send('You sent the name "' + lName + ' and the message ' + messg + '".');
}); 

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
})
```

```html
<div class="Contact_info">
        <h1 id="Resume">Give us some advice</h1>
        <form id="formCritic"  action="http://localhost:3000/myaction"  method="post">
            <input type="text" id="Name" name="Nome" placeholder="Your name.." >
            <textarea class="text_area_submit" id="Questio" name="Questio" placeholder="Just advice us on any problem or any suggestion that can  boost up this web.." ></textarea>

            <input id="submit_text_are" type="submit" value="Submit">
            
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My HTML is very huge, has a lot of CSS too, but I will be focus only in the problem here, so just put on the piece of code that matter.

Just to see if it can help, I will edit this with my head HTML:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Computer, Language Programming">
  <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials for PC and programming language">  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>shadow</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/Index_css.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jQueryJs/MyJquery.js"></script>
  <script src="Js/Base_JavaScritp.js"></script>
  <script src="Js/ServerSide.js"></script>
</head>

<body>....
```

If something on this can lead to the error I am getting, I would appreciate to know.

Again, I'm not posting my whole body here because there are 460 lines, so just to make it simple and attach to the problem, I put just the part that matter

I change my HTML form to method: get

```html
<form id="formCritic"  action="http://localhost:3000/myaction"  method="get">
```

and in js:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was
//deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  const options = {
    root: path.join(__dirname)
  };

  const fileName = 'Index.html'
    res.sendFile(fileName, options)
}); 

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
})
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
    at D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\ServerSide.js:17:11
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at urlencodedParser (D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: "cannot get:" typically means the location you are posting to is incorrect. i don't see any reason that would occur given your code, and the error message doesn't match the action clearly visible in the form element. I suspect the html you are using doesn't directly match what you provided.

Comment: it is exaclity what is on my html, i will edit the post with my head html, just to see if can help in something

Comment: i don't think it'd help, all that matters is the form itself. If you're just submitting with html, nothing outside of the form matters. The form submit does what it does, there's not much magic there.

Comment: thats why i didnt understand what you sad first, i just copy and past here the submitt

Comment: You haven't defined `path`; you need something like `var path = require('node:path');`.

Comment: this 'path' is my root directory ?

Comment: like: var path = require('node:MyRootDirectory/file/subfile');??

Comment: path is a module in js

Answer (score 3):

This is because you haven't defined an endpoint for your GET request. I think you got confused between POST vs GET requests.

you are just sending a POST request at /myaction which is working fine, you can see it in the postman.

I believe you want to send data to /myaction and then display it on your 127.0.0.1/3000 in browser, right?
Add below code to define GET endpoint. also in filename give your .html file name.

```
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    const options = {
        root: path.join(__dirname)
    };
    const fileName = 'your-filename.html'
    res.sendFile(fileName, options)
})
```

also add `app.use(bodyParser.json())` before `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

if i missed something let me know.

Comment: i would like to get the textarea data and display it on 127.0.0.1/3000 in browser,

I changed the method on html to get, and put your code. I edit the question with your answer

Comment: add, const path = require('path') on top

Comment: i change it and now it get: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\vitor\AREA PROGRAMAÇÃO\JavaScript Programando\Site MyProject\Js\Index.html' and on html web is getting: Cannot GET /myaction

Comment: it is a  module that provides utilities for working with file and directory paths. 
example - 
const fullPathOfFile = path.join('/path', 'to', 'your', 'file.txt');

Comment: it seems your index.html file is in js folder, move it out of it to your root folder
OR
do this
const options = {
        root: path.join(__dirname+'/js')
    };

Comment: it is one folder before like:

-index.html;
-js(folder where my ServerSide.js is);
others folders like 
-imagefolder

Comment: see how i used path, initially path.join(__dirname) gives your root directoy.
do this - 
    const htmlFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'index.html');
    res.sendFile(htmlFilePath)

Comment: now when i type http://127.0.0.1:3000/ to see my server on web, it just got me on my website(index unformatted with css). In my html web im just getting : Cannot GET /myaction